# Web Service returning serialized helper objects

Tags: php, web-api, serialization

I had the idea to have a route in my REST API that returns serialized (PHP) helper objects. The client code then can use those objects to format some complex JSON structures for the next request. When the implementation of the REST API changes, I don't have to change the client code. Is this a good idea/common practice/nonsense?

Comment: Have a look at [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).